# After upgrade sdk 33.0 the expo react-native mobile app not working?

Tags: react-native, sdk, expo

I had a SDK v 30.0.0 react-native mobile application in expo framework. After upgraded to SDK 33.0.0, Then I got this error.

I tried lots of methods.

> > Error installing or running app. Error: xcrun exited with non-zero code: 60
> >     ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/Users/kobi.ktk/Desktop/uniexpo/App/Components/StepIndicator/node_modules/@expo/vector-icons/fonts'
> >     Failed building JavaScript bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Check how you use vector icons in your app. 
Path is changed. Example: Path to MaterialIcons.ttf: 
@expo/vector-icons/build/vendor/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/MaterialIcons.ttf

Expo docs howto import etc: 
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/icons/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
rm -rf node_moules package-lock.json
npm i
```